# complex console.log output in cli

Tags: node.js, console.log

I'm creating informational output with `console.log()` in Node.js however, I would like to create a split screen that somehow outputs different data.

Example:
`---------------------------------`
`| value a.1     | value b.1     |`
`| value a.2     | value b.2     |`
`| value a.3     | value b.3     |`
`| value a.4     | value b.4     |`
`| value a.5     | value b.5     |`
`|               | value b.6     |`
`|               | value b.7     |`
`---------------------------------`

It could be that value b.x is updating very fast, and value a.1 very slowly.

What could I use? Maybe something else then `console.log()`?

**UPDATE**:
I needed a UI library for the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a UI library for the console. You're in luck. This sort of thing has been around for a while.

You essentially have two choices:

- https://github.com/chjj/blessed - A simple graphics library for terminals that lets you do stuff like what you're describing above.
- https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses - node bindings for ncurses (this is a standard terminal graphics library).

I think blessed has a nicer API, but the choice is yours!

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of others looking around for more options:

Along with `blessed` and `node-ncurses`, you have `Colors`, `Chalk` and `Terminal-Kit` as well.

However, if one do not want to use `console.log()`, `Terminal-Kit` could be of use.